# Cable remote control for Olympus Audio Recorders possible?

Tags: recorder, remote, control

How to switch an Olympus Audio Recorder on (and maybe off) with a cable remote control?

I am using the Olympus LS-3/LS-7 audiorecorder. Its remote control port is a 2.5-mm-jack-plug, like most Olympus audiorecorders.

Olympus sells an infrared-remote-control, called "[RS30W](http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1320/5125715610_ef2c615644_o.jpg)", that is large, expensive and requires line-of-sight. You can see in the image, that the jack-plug has 4 contacts.

I would like to have a cable remote control, that needs no line of sight. A perfect solution would have a switch with two positions: recording and not-recording. So that I can see and feel if the device is recording.

I have not found a documentation of the pinout of the cable. Canon uses a similar cable-remote-control for their cameras, with a 2.5-mm-jack-plug, but with only three contacts. Depending on the position of the switch, different contacts are shortcut. I feel that a similar solution should be possible for Olympus if the "protocol" is simple enough.

Comment: I have EXACTLY the same question!!
Olympus blocks any inquiry about their remote port, the layout of pins etc.
I do not have the RS30W to tinker with.
My guess is that the 4 prongs carry Voltage/Gnd/On-Off bridge signal to start and stop the device.
It is a shame that the company neither provides such a simple cable nor reveals how to construct one. Their RS30W is overpriced, bulky and will not work over large distances anyways.
Not even FixYa offers a solution, very discouraging...